# How can I convert an R multi-element vector to Python list in R Markdown?

Tags: python, r, r-markdown, reticulate

I have to read some vector created in an R chunk in a Python chunk in an R Markdown document.

I successfully created the vector, but when I try to attribute the R vector to a Python variable via `py_list = r.vector` it just doesn't work.

Here there is a peace of the code:

```
{python ingestao_parcela, eval = py_eval, include = FALSE}
###### IMPORT FEATURE ######
name_layer_tmp = 'parcela_tmp'
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion('C:/Users/CLEITE/AppData/Roaming/ESRI/Desktop10.7/ArcCatalog/Connection to BRP01.sde/SDE_GEO.VANT_PARCELA', arcpy.env.workspace, name_layer_tmp, """ DT_MES_REF = {} """.format(dt_mes_ref))

##### CREATE UNIQUE CODE COLUMN #####
arcpy.AddField_management(name_layer_tmp, 'CONCAT_T', 'TEXT')
arcpy.CalculateField_management(name_layer_tmp, 'CONCAT_T',
""" [ESTADO_FEDERATIVO] & "_" & [CD_HORTO] & "_" & [CD_TALHAO] """, 'VB')

##### R VECTOR TO PYTHON LIST #####
dado_amostral_py = r.dado_amostral
dado_amostral_py = tuple(dado_amostral_py)

##### FEATURE FILTER #####
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion('parcela_tmp', arcpy.env.workspace,
'parcela', """ [CONCAT_T] IN {} """.format(dado_amostral_py))
```

PS: I already checked if the R vector "dado_amostral" was created in R indeed, and it was.

I already checked the reticulate CRAN page and I found something about element types conversion.

What I understand from this article is that if I want to use some object created in R inside a Python chunk I only would have to do like I wrote in the beginning: `py_list = r.vector`.

But when I try to run the R Markdown document, it says that there is no variable such "dado amostral".

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I've just figured out how to do what I wanted.

The solution I found is:

```
{r}
r_to_py(dado_amostral)
```

```
{python}
py_dado_amostral = r.dado_amostral
```